# C# Windows Form: Associating a text box each with selected ListBox Item

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls

I created a CheckedListBox of about 12 Items. I want to dynamically create Textboxes to display and accept an input value from the user on the form each time  an Item is selected.  The Textboxes value is to be associated with the Selected Items Values for storage into some Sql database table when a Button is finally selected.

What I have been able to do so far is to have a single Textbox displayed even when I selected other items from the list box. Below is my Code

```
    private void checkedList_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            int n = 6;
            selectedList.Items.Add(checkedList.SelectedItem.ToString());
            for (int x=0; x < checkedList.SelectedItems.Count; x++)
            {
                TextBox[] txtBoxes = new TextBox[n];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    txtBoxes[i] = new TextBox();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                this.Controls.Add(txtBoxes[i]);
                txtBoxes[i].Location = new Point(450, 100);
                txtBoxes[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 20);
                txtBoxes[i].Validating += new CancelEventHandler(txt_Validating);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            selectedList.Items.Remove(checkedList.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }

    }
    private void InitializeMyListBox()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < selectedList.Items.Count; x++)
        {
            selectedList.SetSelected(x, true);
        }
        // Force the ListBox to scroll back to the top of the list.
        selectedList.TopIndex = 0;
    }
```

What did I do wrong?

Can you please help with this.

Comment: They are all on top of each other, you'll have to pick another Location or use a FlowLayoutPanel.  Creating your own grid control with individual textboxes is rarely not a mistake, always favor DataGridView first.

Answer (score 0):

You have set same location to all TextBoxes.
Try to set something like this:

```
txtBoxes[i].Location = new Point(450 + i*20, 100);
```

Comment: I thank you for your input. The other textBoxes are still not showing even after setting txtBoxes[i].Location = new Point(450 + x*20, 100);

Comment: i made mistake you shoud multiply with i and not x. So use this : txtBoxes[i].Location = new Point(450 + i*20, 100);